# How to increase the number of contents to be stored on a listbox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to store huge amount of data on a listbox. For example, i was about to store more than thousand of words on a listbox, suddenly it stopped accepting inputs on the collection.

Is there any way to increase the limit of contents to be stored on a listbox in c#?

Comment: Is it WPF, Winforms or asp.net? Could you supply us with some code?

Comment: A 1,000+ elements in a list box sounds like bad design. Why do you need so many? A different UI would be a better solution.

Comment: May I ask how many items you are adding and what you are using it for? It seems like a really bad practise.

Comment: Are you getting any errors output?

Comment: As far as I know the size of collections is restricted by its index which is an integer value. If you really handle more that 2^31 - 1 (= 2,147,483,647) items a listbox isn't the best control to show them.

Comment: im trying to store words on the listbox... for example, number of words to be found starting with letter A and so on... and i'll be using this words on my listbox as my dictionary... any recommendations or alternatives??

Comment: I just tried to add 100000 items to a list box in win forms, and it worked fine. So show us the relevant parts of your code, what you are describing might not be the real cause of your problem.

Comment: is it one item per row? i'm using the Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition.. under it i choose the Windows Forms Application project. 

after which, i stored 5 Letter Words on the listbox, later on i discovered that it stopped on the words that starts at m, and after that i can't store any words again on that listbox.. 

so does it mean that the listbox has its maximum or limits with the content to be stored on the listbox?

Comment: There's a bug in the Vista implementation of the native listbox control, you can't scroll past 65536 + number of visible items.  Not fixed in Win7, they surely didn't think it important enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Virtualizing listbox is the correct technical answer.  However, I think the more important question is **Why**, not **How**.  IMHO, in a practical sense, a listbox with 1000+ items is unusable in almost all cases.  How will a user remember the choices they have seen or selected as they scroll further into the 1000+ items?

You and your users might be better served by posting a question on the sibling site here at StackExchange, [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com).  There you might ask for the best way to present a very large number of choices to a user.

Comment: heres a reason why i'm storing alot of data on the listbox.. im creating an application where it generates random patterns and letters.. after which, the system will generate possible combinations out from those patterns and letters to form a word that is present on the system dictionary....

well actually i'm going to use those listboxes to store all words to serve as my system dictionary.. on the main form i'm going to call all those words and store it on an arraylist..then compare the generated words on the items on the arraylist to check if the generated words are present on the system...

Comment: Sounds like you are just using it as a data structure, there are better data structures in the .Net library for managing dictionaries and large collections of data objects.  Creating a windows object just for data storage carries a lot of overhead for no value.  If you are also using the list-box for presentation, I would again say that you need to present a more usable interface to the user

Answer (score 0):

In WPF the ListBox control is a virtualizing listbox - in that it only holds in memory whats currently in view in the control.  That makes it able to handle very large backing data collections.  Its not clear whether your in WPF or forms - if in forms maybe you need to look at a virtualizing listbox.

You might try something like: [this](http://www.viblend.com/products/net/windows-forms/controls/listbox.aspx) that appears to be a winforms compatible listbox built using wpf (so will probably be virtualizaing) - why not ask them about large data sets.

Comment: Im using Windows Forms Application. Can i increase the maximum rows of the listbox? where in i could store huge amount of words on the listbox? like 1 word per row to be consumed..

Comment: @Rexon Ive updated answer with a winfoms control that I suspect is virtualizing - you'd have to check vendor to be sure.